# installing ruby-2.0.0 Error running 'make -j4',

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

Does anyone have had this same error before while installing `ruby 2.0.0` in `rails 4.0`?

all this in a MAC OS X 10.8.2

```
Error running 'make -j4'
```

couldn't find any answers.

Comment: There must be some log?  Why not post that?

Comment: any console output? what command are you using?

Comment: after a lot of search and test this worked out:                      $CC=clang rvm install 2.0.0 -C --enable-shared, --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl` --verify-downloads 1                        $rvm use 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I agree with devnull, we would need a log of some sort to narrow down your problem.

Though I did just install ruby 2.0 on a mac 10.8.4 yesterday using [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install). 
Try following the instructions [here](https://coderwall.com/p/tptocq). That made it very simple.

Comment: after a lot of search and test this worked out:                      $CC=clang rvm install 2.0.0 -C --enable-shared, --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl` --verify-downloads 1                        $rvm use 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here's the process I went through. Some of the commands might be specific to my environment and you may have to adjust accordingly. This process was a mix and mash of recommendations from various sources, but also following along with whatever the output spit out. I found that I was unable to install ruby 2.0 just from following other stack overflow threads as written, so I had to improvise, somewhat. Hope this helps.

1. Made sure i downloaded the latest Xcode and Command Line tool (seems to be the general recommendation out there)
2. run 'brew doctor'
3. run 'brew update'
4. run 'rvm requirements'
5. run 'rvm get head'
6. Kept seeing this error  "Can not automatically remove lines with 'rvm_autolibs_flag=' from '/etc/rvmrc', please clean it manually."
7. run 'rvmsudo --debug'  #as recommended in terminal, but this still wasn't fixing the problem, so i tried....
8. run 'rvmsudo rvm get head'  #because the output recommended 'prefix the command with rvmsudo to fix it'
9. run 'rvm requirements'
10. run 'rvm install 2.0.0'    #error "There is no checksum for 'http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-2.0.5.tgz' or 'rubygems-2.0.5.tgz', it's not possible to validate it.......If that does not resolve the issue and you wish to continue with unverified download
    add '--verify-downloads 1' after the command."
11. run 'rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --verify-downloads 1'
12. run 'rvm default 2.0.0'

And it finally worked. My Ruby verison is now  ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0].